# Why do these points lie on a straight line?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I didn't understand why $P_7$, $P_8$, and $P_9$ lie on a straight line in this proposition in Fulton's book.

[image]

**The corollary:**

[image]

**The definition of $F\cdot G$**

[image]

I need help, maybe I didn't understand what is exactly $F\cdot G$.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection cycle basically stores the data of how curves $F$ and $G$ intersect. It keeps the points of intersection, as well as their intersection number at those points. Bezout's theorem tells you that if you have two projective plane curves $F$ and $G$ of degree $n$ and $m$ respectively, then they intersect at $mn$ points *counting multiplicity of intersections*. In the language of  cycles, the zero cycle  $F\bullet G $ has degree $mn$ (recall that the degree of a zero cycle is just the sum of the coefficients).

Now if we make the substitutions that the proof of Prop 2 says to make in the proof, we check:

- $F\cap G$ consists of simple points of $F.$ Well $F\cap G$ is where $C$ intersects $Q.$ From $Q\bullet C= P_1 + \cdots + P_6$ we can read off that they intersect precisely at $P_1, \cdots, P_6$, and we are assume they are simple points on $C.$
- $H\bullet F \geq G\bullet F.$ This is true since $H\bullet F$ in this case is $P_1 + \cdots + P_9$ and $G\bullet F = P_1 + \cdots + P_6.$

So the conditions are satisfied and there is some curve $B$ such that $B\bullet C = P_7 + P_8 + P_9.$

Now what does Bezout's theorem tell you about the degree of $B$ ?

Comment: The degree of B is 1, then we have the result

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just one question, why the degree of $B\cdot C$ has to be $3$? I know the number of points is three, but why does the degree of the curve has to be the same number of the points?

Comment: @user42912 Bezout's theorem implies that the sum of the coefficients of $F\bullet G$ is the product of their degrees. Here that tells us that the product of the degree of $B$ with the degree of $C$ is $3.$ But we know $C$ is a cubic so it has degree $3.$ This means $B$ has degree $1$, i.e. it is a straight line. Now by definition of intersection cycles, $P_7, P_8, P_9$ are the points where $B$ intersects $C.$ In particular, they lie on the straight line $B$.

Comment: yes, yes, of course. Thanks again.